# Rxjs forkJoin map values from array dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, javascript-objects

Hi I've an array of Boolean observables and want to perform logical AND operation but as of now I'm passing static values a, b but I don't know how many values would be there inside `totalKeys` array.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

...
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
private totalKeys: Observable<Boolean>[] = [];
// some logic
  
return forkJoin(this.totalKeys).pipe(
    map(([a, b]) => a && b)
  );
};
```

How can I dynamically add elements to map array and use logical AND on those instead of passing static params to map operator.

Comment: You can use the reduce() operator to perform a logical AND operation on the elements of an array
```return forkJoin(this.totalKeys).pipe(
  map(values => values.reduce((acc, val) => acc && val))
);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `every` :

which will look like following for you.

`map(items => items.every(Boolean))`

The way it works is following : every item is converted to a `boolean` and `every` will check that every item is true. this is semanticly equivalent to having `&&` on every item.

Comment: Would be great if you can elaborate more on this, how would I perform AND operation on each value.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler shouldn't it be `map(items => items.every(Boolean))`?

Comment: @akotech yes, you're right

Answer (score 1):

**RxJS**

- [every](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/every) operator

[image]

like this

```
merge(...totalKeys).pipe(every(identity))
```